# Casting a spell and then preparing a new one while the previous is still in effect

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting

Classes like the artificer can prepare a new spell list in 1 minute, can an artificer cast a long-duration spell such as false life (1 hour), and immediately prepare a new spell list while retaining false life's effects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you cast a spell just before the end of a long rest?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110485/can-you-cast-a-spell-just-before-the-end-of-a-long-rest)

Comment: @Someone_Evil I don't think it's a duplicate. The other question is rather cheesy and I'm 95% sure my DM wouldn't allow it. This, on the other hand, is a valid use of a class feature imho (provided it works, I haven't combed through the rules).

Comment: @Someone_Evil not really, resting and preparing spells are different mechanics with different constraints. Though thanks for the suggestion nontheless.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### An Artificer cannot change their prepared spell list in 1 minute

[Artificers prepare their spell list](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer) as follows:

> You can change your list of prepared spells **when you finish a long rest**.

A long rest takes eight hours, (four if you're an elf).

During that long rest, in order to change your spell list you must spend time:

> tinkering with your spellcasting focuses: at least 1 minute per spell level for each spell on your list.

**However, these changes won't be in effect until you 'finish a long rest'.**

**That said, [you can indeed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110485/40921) 'cast a long-duration spell [..] and then immediately prepare a new spell list while retaining [its] effects'.**

Unfortunately *[false life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/false-life)* wouldn't work that well for this - as its duration is only an hour long, much shorter than the length of a long rest - but something like *[water breathing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/water-breathing)* (duration 24 hours) would.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I don't know how I missed the long rest part